# JQuery "onclick" event plus "onload"

Tags: jquery

Sometimes I encount following problem:
I am using asp.net and JQuery on client side. For example I want to show/hide texbox depending on state of checkbox. I write something like this:

```
   $(function() {         

       $('#<%=chbMyCheckbox.ClientID %>').click(function(event) {

           if (this.checked) {
             $('#txFirstAid').show();
           } else {
             $('#txFirstAid').hide();
           }
       });
   });
```

It works fine. But I also want to run this code when page is just loaded. Sure, I can move code to separate function like this:

```
   $(function() {         
         myFunc();
       $('#<%=chbMyCheckbox.ClientID %>').click(function(event) {
           myFunc();

       });

          function myFunc()
          {
           if (this.checked) {
             $('#txFirstAid').show();
           } else {
             $('#txFirstAid').hide();
           }
          }
   });
```

The question is: Is it possible somehow not to move code otside, and write something like this

```
$('#<%=chbMyCheckbox.ClientID %>').click(function(event).onloadEvent()
{
    bla-bla
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use jquery's `trigger()` method to fire the click event onLoad.

for example, register a click event:

`$('#someElement').on('click', function () { console.log('I BE CLICkED') });`

The trigger it with:

`$('#someElement').trigger('click');`

You can trigger any event using `trigger()` as well as fire custom events. (which allow you to bind to event fired by plugins etc.

[The full trigger documentation is here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), and heres a good post on using [custom events in jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/)

Answer (score 0):

How about hiding the textbox on the server when rendering the page? So the user cant see the textbox before domready.